# Find all values for a and b such that two vectors are not perpendicular

Tags: vectors, recreational-mathematics, 3d

I'm stuck on this question that asks to find all values for a and b such that two vectors u = (-1, 2, a-2), and v = (b, 4, -2) are not perpendicular.

I know that if the dot product of u.v = 0 then the two vectors are perpendicular. I applied the dot product and got:

-b + +12 -2a.

And i rearranged the equation to find a and b, however when i put them back into the equation it gets messy. Any advice on how to tack this problem, thanks.

Comment: So you have arrived at
$$
\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} \neq 0 \qquad \Leftrightarrow \qquad b+ 2 a \neq 12
$$
So that's the set of solutions. There are infinitely many, as I interpret it ... So "almost all" values of $a$ and $b$ work here, as one can guess. The only requirement is that $b+2a$ is not equal to $12$.

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$\begin{align}
\vec{u} \text{ and } \vec{v} \text{ perpendicular} & \iff \vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = 0, \\
& \iff -b + 12 - 2a = 0, \\
& \iff b + 2a = 12.
\end{align}$$

Just as what you got. You can check for example, choosing $b = 0$, we get $2a = 12$ and hence, $a = 6$ and plugging this back into your original vector, we have that they are indeed perpendicular.

What you wanted was **not** perpendicular. So just negate our result above to have:

$$\vec{u} \text{ and } \vec{v} \text{ not perpendicular} \iff b + 2a \neq 12.$$

So if you fix your favorite $a$, then taking $b \neq 12 - 2a$ i.e. any $b$ not of this form renders $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ not perpendicular.

For example: Fix $a = 0$. We don't want $b = 12 - 2a = 12$. So take, say, $b = 1$, then

$$\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = (-1, 2, -2) \cdot (1, 4, -2) \neq 0.$$

But then since $a$ can be any real number, there are infinitely many solutions for which $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} \neq 0$ and they admit the form

$$b +2a \neq 12$$

or equivalently,

$$a \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } b \neq 12 - 2a.$$